# Very Simple PHP Alert Issue

Tags: php

Right now, if a user places an order on my site and the bank rejects the order for any reason (e.g. insufficient funds, wrong address, etc) the page does not display an error message or inform the customer he hasn't been charged at all.

I would like to modify this code on my site to give a quick popup alert stating 'Transaction Failed ...... etc etc'. Please take a look at the code below and let me know what I should do to change it. I just can't figure it out for some reason.

```
else {
  $emsg =  base64_encode($response->error_message);
  header('location: payment.php?invalid='.$emsg.'');
 }    
else{

   echo 'Failed Transaction';
}

?>
```

Right now, the only thing that indicates to the customer that his payment failed is the URL will change at the end to 'invalid='.

I would simply like to have a quick alert message displayed if the payment fails.

How can I do this? I will be greatly appreciative of any help!

Comment: why do you have 2 `else`?

Comment: popup alert requires client side (javascript) changes...

Comment: as Mario said 2 else's only the first one is processed it should be an else if  then an else

Comment: as @luiges90 said, you need an client side alert. PHP is only for server side programming! You can change everything on your file you send to the client but nothing more!!

Comment: In fact, you can write HTML and javascript in a PHP file, but the questioner showed no HTML/Javascript code. To be clear, PHP is used to modify/preprocess an HTML and send the HTML to the client

Comment: there should not be two `else` blocks and also make sure that there is absolutely NO HTML before the call to `header()`, if there is HTML before the header call it will not work.

Comment: OK I will try now with the elseif to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: hahaha two else's, new language :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have 2 else's, you need to use an elseif instead

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

The proper structure would look like

```
if (condition == true){

}elseif (a_different_condition == true){

}else{
    //this happens if neither of the first two trigger
}
```

As far as a popup alert goes, you'd need to do that on the client side with Javascript.

Documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp